# What is the difference between a lawlike sequence of only zeros and a lawless sequence of only zeros in Intuitionism

Tags: logic, real-numbers, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In our class the profosser mentioned that there is a difference between a lawlike sequence of only zeros and a lawless sequence of only zeros in Intuitionism but I didn't quiet understood.
In both we can think of it as a cauchy sequence and the real number is the limit which is zero, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When talking about lawless sequences, it's important to keep in mind what the *a priori* possible terms of the sequence are; usually they are either natural numbers, or sometimes just $0$ and $1$.  In the degenerate case where the only *a priori* possibility is $0$, there would be no difference between a lawless sequence and a lawlike one. I confess that I've never seen this degenerate case  mentioned, and the only reason I mention it here is to avoid its coming up as an exception to what I write below.  So from now on, I'll assume that there is at least one nonzero *a priori* possibility, say $1$.

In this situation (which is undoubtedly what the professor had in mind) I don't think "a lawless sequence of only zeros" makes sense from an intuitionistic point of view.  According to intuitionism, all one can ever know about a lawless sequence is that it is lawless, that the *a priori* possible terms are such-and-such, and that a finite initial segment of the sequence is so-and-so. Even if all of the finitely many terms already chosen are $0$ we can't know that all the future choices will also be $0$.  To talk about a lawless sequence consisting of only $0$'s, we'd have to adopt the viewpoint of the whole sequence (all of its terms) already having been chosen, and (as far as I know) this viewpoint is not admitted in intuitionistic mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

See :

- Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, [Constructivism in mathematics: An Introduction. Volume I](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&pg=PA207) (1988), page 207:

Both are varieties of *choice sequence*, a peculiar object of Intuitionistic mathematics.

A choice sequnce is a sort of process not necessarily predetermined by a law or algorithm.

A *lawlike* sequence $a$ is a sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ of numbers generated by a "law": a procedure, an algorithm.

From a non-Brouwerian point of view : "lawlike" = "recursive".

A *lawless* sequence $\alpha$ of e.g. *natural* is a process of choosing its values $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \ldots \in \mathbb N$ such that at each stage in the generation of $\alpha$ we know only finitely many values.

At each stage $n$ of the process we are not able to impose general restrictions on future values; we cannot, for example, decide that all values to be chosen after stage $n$ are to be even.

Thus, we can never assert that its value will coincide with the values of some lawlike sequence.

Consider the variable $a$ ranging over *lawlike* sequences; in order to assert $\exists a \ (\alpha = a)$, we must *know* at some stage that $\alpha=a$ for some lawlike $a$, which is not. Thus, we have:

> $\forall \alpha \ \lnot \exists a \ (\alpha=a)$.

---

See :

- Errett Bishop & Douglas Bridges, [Constructive Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=GF8lBAAAQBAJ&pg=Pa9) (1985), page 9 for criticism:

> [Brouwer] introduced the method of free-choice sequences for constructing the continuum, as a consequnce of which the continuum canno be discrete because it is not well enough defined.

---

See also [Intuitionism : The *continuum*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/#TheCon) on *choice sequences*, both *lawlike* and *lawless*.